# Comment traduire « bank holiday weekend » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

En Angleterre, nous appelons un week-end avec un jour férié le lundi « *a bank holiday weekend* », comme ce week-end par exemple.

J'ai utilisé l'expression « un week-end férié », mais mon ami français ne me comprend pas sans une explication. Je pense que ce n'est pas la traduction idéale.

Est-ce qu'il y a une meilleure traduction ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On dit en général un *week-end de trois jours*, ou *week-end prolongé* (que je trouve un peu moins naturel). [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week-end_prolong%C3%A9) propose *longue fin de semaine* au Canada (en France, ce n'est pas utilisé).

Si le jour férié tombe un jeudi ou un mardi, beaucoup d'entreprises ferment le vendredi ou le lundi, et on parle de *pont* (*le pont de l'Ascension*). « Faire le pont » signifie ne pas travailler un jour de pont.

Comment: Et le 'pont' est ce qui est intéressant dans cette question, car tout comme il n'y a pas de mot pour 'bank holiday week-end' en français, il n'y a pas de mot pour 'pont' en anglais, car ça n'existe pas :) Ici en Suisse, j'entends aussi dire 'long week-end', ça marche aussi en France?

Comment: @Benjol Ça peut marcher, mais ça dépend un peu du contexte. « J'ai profité du long week-end pour me reposer » → oui. « Ça a été un long week-end, mon bébé est malade et je n'ai pas fermé l'œil » → ça peut très bien être juste samedi et dimanche.

Comment: @Gilles : Comme en anglais, d'ailleurs. « I had a really long weekend; my kid's sick and I barely slept at all. »

Answer (score 11):

L'expression que j'ai le plus entendue pour décrire cela est **« week-end prolongé »**. Elle désigne indifférement tous les week-ends de trois jours (ou plus !), donc si je pose un jour de congé vendredi, cela me fait également un week-end prolongé.

Pour être plus spécifique, j'employerais « week-end prolongé par un jour férié ». *Quite a mouthful!*

Comment: En étendant à *faire le pont* quand on ne travaille pas entre deux jours fériés ou un week-end et un jour férié (par exemple en posant un jour de congés un lundi lorsqu'un mardi est férié, je *fais le pont*).
J'ai aussi entendu, quand on pose plus d'un jour, *faire le viaduc*.

Answer (score 4):

Je suis un anglophone qui travaille en France avec uniquement des francophones. Au bureau mes collègues utilisent le terme anglais **« long weekend »** pour un weekend précédé ou suivi d'un jour férié.

Pour préciser le nom de la fête on dit « weekend de Pâques » ou « l'Ascension catholique ».

Juste une remarque : il paraît que le weekend est une invention anglaise et comme beaucoup des mots importés de l'anglais, il existe en français des termes anglais ainsi que leurs traductions, comme **« week-end prolongé »**.

Answer (score 1):

Dans mon entourage, on utilise beaucoup **« Un week-end de trois jours »**.