# Four day weekend?

Tags: usage

Does there exist a colloquial expression in French for taking an additional day more when it comes to making a three day long weekend into four days?

I vaguely remember something of this sort does exist.

**Addendum:**

This question does not ask for a colloquial expression for such a situation: [Comment traduire « bank holiday weekend » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/668/comment-traduire-bank-holiday-weekend)

Comment: You might be thinking of [faire le pont](https://www.thoughtco.com/french-expression-faire-le-pont-1371485), but that's more for making a 4-day weekend out of a **2-day** one.

Comment: In canadian french *un long weekend* exist for 3 days weekend (used with the anglicism), it could be told for 4 days weekends, but it's not specific to such.

Comment: @PapaPoule  Both these comments deserve to be turned out into  an answer. Why not make it as a wiki? By the end of the day you will have people making mutiple answers...

Comment: See also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/668/comment-traduire-bank-holiday-weekend

Comment: @jlliagre Missed it, might as well ask for the question to be closed then.

Comment: @Laure The questions are not identical but quite close indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a community wiki including the answers that were made as comments.

---

There are several such possibilites.

If you really want to specify the weekend is a four day one you can say *weekend de 4 jours*. From the site Tout pratique.com:

> Possibilité d’un weekend de 4 jours
> Le lundi de Pâques tombant le lundi 22 avril, le salarié peut demander à prendre le vendredi 19 ou le mardi 23 pour bénéficier d’un weekend de 4 jours.([*Quels sont les week end et jours de congé en 2019*](https://www.toutpratique.com/12-Savoir-vivre/6350-quels-sont-les-week-end-et-jours-de-conge-en-2019.php))

*Faire le pont* is also a possibility, it means to take the day(s) off between two holidays or between a holiday and a weekend. Definition [in the TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pont):

> Faire le pont. Chômer un ou plusieurs jours ouvrables, situé(s) entre deux jours fériés (ou entre un jour férié et un week-end); avoir ce congé de quelques jours.

*Un long weekend* is a long weekend that's made possible because of a bank holiday connected to a weekend. It lasts a minimum of three days and must either start on the Friday or end on the Monday.

> Un long week-end ou longue fin de semaine est un week-end prolongé en raison d'un jour férié et composé d'au moins trois jours, débutant un vendredi ou/et se terminant un lundi. ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_week-end))

When two bank holidays happen to occur in the same week or around the same week-end, for example the first one on Tuesday and the second one on Thursday, using two vacation days lead to a seven days break which is often called a *[viaduc](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/viaduc)*.

Comment: @PapaPoule Didn't see the mistake on the month! Better change the example then...

Comment: It does make more sense to do it that way (but seeing June 31st in print is always such a treat)!

Comment: Very generous of you to make this a community wiki response. Thank you, Laure.

Comment: @KenGraham Well, it's the spirit of sharing on SE isn't it? Not fair when people make good answers as comments and others take their ideas and gain reputation this way. Happened again here after I'd written my comment to Papa Poule (can't include 2 in a comment, but  of course yagmoth555 was included as well).

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks for teaching me that extension of the *pont*. We learn every day!

Answer (score 3):

If Thursday or Tuesday is a holiday and you take Friday or Monday off then this is a 'pont', i.e. you create a *bridge* between week-end and holiday. In other cases, you may call it 'week-end prolongé'.

Answer (score 3):

The 11th of November is a public holiday in France.  This year it's a Monday.  If you wanted to extend the three-day weekend to the Tuesday or start it as early as Friday the 8th you could say :

> - J'ai posé un jour de congé le 12/le 8 pour avoir un week-end de quatre jours.

Shorter versions are possible:

> - J'ai posé le mardi/le vendredi pour avoir un week-end de quatre jours.
> - J'ai posé le 12/le 8 pour avoir un week-end de quatre jours

*Poser un jour de congé* does not necessarily apply to weekend situations but very often people do it to create short holidays by extending three-day weekends or by filling the gap between the weekend and bank holidays if they fall on a Thursday or a Tuesday.